# Factory Reset Cisco SPA504G without admin password

Tags: voip

I've been trying to factory reset some SPA50x phones, specifically the 504G but the old provider has locked out everything.

I need to reset about 50 phones for use with a new service. I've man in the middle'd their provisioning server, but the phone profiles are compiled with SPC.

I've found a reference to how the old provider created the compiled profiles, and I have recompiled a new profile overriding the Admin_Passwd in the config file, but the phone simply complained that the config file was corrupted.

The phone is configured for SIP, but I have tried connecting it to a UC540 to see what would happen. The phone is able to re provisioned against it, but I still can't reset it without the admin password. This was just for testing anyways, since I actually need the phones connected to Asterisk.

I am very close to considering opening the phone and looking for a jtag port or some other way to reset these phones. I have a single phone on my desk right now that I can play with. I am hoping to find a repeatable solution to this.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can successfully provision the phone by intercepting its provisioning requests, you should be able to reset the admin password. It's just one more field in the provisioning file (and indeed, in this case it can be the *only* field).

You shouldn't even really *need* to compile it with SPC; I only serve plain XML files to my devices.

A trivial XML file to reset the admin password would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<flat-profile>
    <Admin_Passwd ua="na">changeme</Admin_Passwd>
</flat-profile>
```

Your only trick there will be serving it with a MIME type of `application/xml` when the filename is probably something like `spa####.cfg`, but either a tweak to your web server config or doing it in a scripting language like PHP should solve that.

Or you can do it in plain text format compiled with SPC, if you can figure out the right parameters to encrypt it with. (You might be able to tease this info out of the phone, but I wouldn't hold my breath.)

Finally, you may be able to get the phone to resync to a URL of your choice (if this hasn't been restricted) by talking to the phone's internal web server with a crafted URL:

```
http://10.48.203.15/admin/resync?http://10.48.207.1/reset_password.xml
```

For more, you may find the [Cisco Small Business IP Telephony Devices Provisioning Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpvga/ata/provisioning/guide/Cisco_Small_Business_IP_Telephony_Provisioning_Guide.pdf) useful.

Comment: If it wants `XMLDefault.cnf.xml` from your TFTP server, you _should_ just be able to feed it the XML shown above, and the admin password should then be reset. Did you try it?

Comment: Hm. I don't have any spare devices to play with (they're legacy and being phased out here) so I'm rather out of ideas. I'd probably call Cisco next.

Comment: Unbelievable, the url trick allowed me to get into my phone without a password. Crazy how easy it is to hack some things.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reset a Cisco SPG525G2 back to factory configuration is:

1. Remove power from the device, wait 5 seconds
2. Restore power.  Wait for the Cisco Logo to appear
3. The Cisco Logo will be replaced with a boot animation.  As soon as this happens, press the "Speaker Button" three times.  A menu will appear.
4. Select Recovery (option 1)
5. Press OK

The phone will reboot to factory settings.